# Image zoom/grow in a thumbnail

Tags: html, css

I have kind of a thumbnail with an image and some text inside. When I hover over the image, it zooms in. 
Here is a fiddle:
    https://jsfiddle.net/ShiroiOkami/r1awd3b4/

I want to achieve an effect that the image just zooms in, but it's size stays the same. I don't want it to grow. How to do it?

P.S. the code for instance:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg" style="width:150px;" class="grow">
  <div class="description">
    <h3>
    Some title
    </h3>
    <p>
    some text
    </p>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.grow{
        transition: all .2s ease-in-out; 
-webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out; 
   -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out; 
    -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out; 
     -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out; 
}

.grow:hover{
        transform: scale(1.1);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
   -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
     -o-transform: scale(1.1);
}

.description{
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Comment: but if the size of the box is the same, how is it possible to zoom the whole image?

Comment: is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/r1awd3b4/2/

Comment: not exactly, but the question is already answered, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed your fiddle, so you'll get the required effect: https://jsfiddle.net/r1awd3b4/1/

What I've done is add an extra wrapper `div` around the image:

```
<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img src="..." class="grow">  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img-wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-wrapper img{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Now the image can grow all it wants but since the wrapper will not, the image will not 'grow', but just 'zoom'.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

may be you mean this effect?:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="img-container">
        <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg" style="width:150px;" class="grow">
    </div>
    <div class="description">
        <h3>Some title</h3>
        <p>some text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.img-container {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
 }
```

Comment: Yes, that's the effect! Thank you